# Dispatcher.Invoke hangs when the main thread called Thread.Join

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having a problem, for which I am not able to find a solution. The problem is as follows:

In the main thread (the default thread), I am starting a thread and then immediately in the main thread, I wait for the thread's exit by calling `Thread.Join` on the spawned thread. When I do that if the spawned thread tries to callback in the main thread's context by calling `Dispatcher.Invoke`, it hangs. Any ideas how I can allow the callback?

The callback has the logic to signal the thread to exit. Without executing the callback, the thread will never exit, and so the main thread is also stuck.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of starting a new thread if you just wait for it to complete ? Just do the work on the main thread...

Comment: Unfortunately it is a third party library that will spawn a thread and notify us with an event handler via Dispatcher.invoke when it does something. We use that event handler to stop the thread as well

Comment: Then you can't use Thread.Join, because it blocks the main thread so it will be unable to react to process Invoke calls

Comment: BTW, what's the name of that library ? just to make sure I never use it ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but you may try BeginInvoke instead of Invoke

Comment: When I tried that at least the thread issuing begininvoke is responsive but hte invoke never succeeds as the main thread is in thread.join state.

Answer (score -1):

If you're only going to be waiting on the thread to terminate, you could simply have a polling loop, like this:

```
// var otherThread = ...;
volatile bool terminate = false;

while (!terminate)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
otherThread.Join();
```

Then, leave it up to the callbacks to set the terminate flag to true once you're ready to join.

Comment: That worked. But had to add Application.Doevents inside the while loop so that the callback gets executed when the dispatcher.invoke is used. Don't like the solution but at least it works!!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem which I finally solved in this way:

```
do{
    // Force the dispatcher to run the queued operations 
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(delegate { }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}while(!otherthread.Join(1));
```

This produces a Join that doesn't block because of GUI-operations on the other thread.

The main trick here is the blocking `Invoke` with an empty delegate (no-operation), but with a priority setting that is less than all other items in the queue. That forces the dispatcher to work through the entire queue. (The default priority is `DispatcherPriority.Normal = 9`, so my `DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle = 3` is well under.)

The Join() call uses a 1 ms time out, and re-empties the dispatcher queue as long as the join isn't successful.